# Unable to remove d3 transition despite calling interrupt on selection

Tags: d3.js

I have a transition running on some circles in d3. The transition brings the circles into view, and updates a text display with their time stamp:

```
var component = this;
select(this.node).select("#circles").selectAll(".pin")
    .data(this.props.data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle", ".pin")
    .attr("r", 5/component.state.zoomScale)
    .style("fill", "#ff0000")
    .style("opacity", "0.0")
    .transition()
    .on("start", function(d, i) {
      if (i % component.props.multiplier == 0) {
        select("#timer").text(d.time);
      }
    })
    .style("opacity", "1.0")
    .delay(function(d, i) {return d.delay/component.props.multiplier;});
```

If my component receives new data, I want to stop any running transitions on the circles, clear the text and remove the circles:

```
var circles = select(this.node).select("#circles").selectAll(".pin");
if (!circles.empty()) {
  circles.interrupt();
  select("#timer").text(""); //This is my time display that I want to clear
  circles.remove();
```

While the circles are removed fine, the text reappears after being removed suggesting the transition was never actually stopped. How do I correctly stop the transition running on my circles? I am using d3.js v4 within ReactJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set the class separate and not with the `append` call.

Your selection to interrupt does select nothing, there is no circle with that class.

```
var component = this;
select(this.node).select("#circles").selectAll(".pin")
    .data(this.props.data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "pin")
    .attr("r", 5/component.state.zoomScale)
    .style("fill", "#ff0000")
    .style("opacity", "0.0")
    .transition()
    .on("start", function(d, i) {
      if (i % component.props.multiplier == 0) {
        select("#timer").text(d.time);
      }
    })
    .style("opacity", "1.0")
    .delay(function(d, i) {return d.delay/component.props.multiplier;});
```